# In the following CSS layout how can I make my arrow right aligned?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a mockup here

http://jsfiddle.net/pJCfE/

At the moment the down arrow is sitting next to 'All Services'.  I would like to make it right aligned.  How can I do this?

Comment: [float it right](http://jsfiddle.net/mowglisanu/pJCfE/3/).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add class "pull-right" to the caret

```
<span class="caret pull-right">
```

It's one of the utility classes included in bootstrap: https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/blob/master/less/utilities.less

Comment: As a suggestion, with this solution you can use an icon instead of a caret, http://jsfiddle.net/pJCfE/4/. Might use this in the future :) +1

Comment: it doesn't stay vertically in the middle when using pull-right (float)

Answer (score 8):

I lack of reputation for commenting best answer, but I have simple clarification in case "it doesn't stay vertically in the middle when using pull-right (float)". Solution is:

```
<span class="pull-right">
        <span class="caret"></span>
    </span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Previous answer doesn't keep carte's vertical align, as @Omu says. Instead, you should extend .caret's css class:

```
.caret {
  position: absolute;
  right: 1%;
  top: 45%;
}
```

Check it out >> https://jsfiddle.net/twtvcx4n/